# vbnet dynamic button that when is erased it will erase the text from textbox

Tags: vb.net

my project is implemented in vb net.I have one main form which has button1 and a flowoutpanel.
When i press the button,dynamically a button is displayed and placed inside the flowoutpanel.
At the same time it takes the selected text from combobox1 and displays it on the dynamic button property.
It is also saved in another combo box which stores all the strings in order to be taken later on and by pressing save to be displayed on a text box.
If i click the dynamic button it closes and disappears.
And here is where i am stuck.
I would like to know if there is any way when i remove the dynamic button,to also remove its text property which is displayed from the combo box that stores the strings.
I want to do this because when you choose a string value from the combobox1 and add many dynamic buttons ,you may want to erase the first one.
But in that case it will not erase the proper string value from the combo box that stores them.
In other words i a looking for a way to add to the dynamic button_click sub (as you can see from my code),something that will erase from the combo box the text value of the first dynamic button..
I have tried something like :Me.FlowLayoutPanel4.Controls.RemoveAt(0) but it will erase the value at position 0.
Thank you in advance, i am attaching my code below.

```
     Private Sub DynamicButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Dynamic Button is clicked.")
    Me.FlowLayoutPanel5.Controls.RemoveAt(0)

End Sub
```

The above is the code that is triggered when the button is clicked.

Below s the code to create the button dynamically:

```
     Sub CreateDynamicButton()
    ' Create a Button object 
    Dim dynamicButton As New Button

    ' Set Button properties

    dynamicButton.Location = New Point(584, 90)
    dynamicButton.Height = 20
    dynamicButton.Width = 52
    ' Set background and foreground
    dynamicButton.BackColor = Color.Green
    dynamicButton.ForeColor = Color.Blue
    dynamicButton.Text = ComboBox6.Text
    dynamicButton.Name = "DynamicButton"
    dynamicButton.Font = New Font("Georgia", 8)
    AddHandler dynamicButton.Click, AddressOf DynamicButton_Click
    ' Add Button to the Form. Placement of the Button
    ' will be based on the Location and Size of button

    Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(dynamicButton)

End Sub
```

Or if there is a way to do something like that:

```
            textbox.text=dynamicbutton.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Subroutine to do the job for you something like this should work, it is using the  [`ComboBox.ObjectCollection.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.contains(v=vs.110).aspx) method to check if the item is present, then it is using the
 [`ComboBox.ObjectCollection.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the index position of the item so that you can remove it with the [`ComboBox.ObjectCollection.RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
Public Sub RemoveItem(item As String, values As ComboBox.ObjectCollection)
    If values.Contains(item) Then
        values.RemoveAt(values.IndexOf(item))
    End If
End Sub
```

Usuage:

```
RemoveItem("your string value here", ComboBox1.Items)
```